# Why does XSensors produce only one value?

Tags: 12.04, lm-sensors

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. Up until minutes ago XSensors was working fine. I had to restart due to some updates and it stopped working. By that I mean that it only displays one temperature (the other tab is just blank):

[image: link to screenshot]

Here is my the output from `$ sensors`, to show that there is other data being detected:

```
k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +27.2°C  (high = +70.0°C)
                       (crit = +90.0°C, hyst = +87.0°C)

fam15h_power-pci-00c4
Adapter: PCI adapter
power1:      115.97 W  (crit = 124.77 W)

it8720-isa-0228
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:          +1.41 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in1:          +1.47 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in2:          +3.38 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
+5V:          +2.94 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in4:          +3.06 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in5:          +2.91 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
in6:          +4.08 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)  ALARM
5VSB:         +2.96 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)
Vbat:         +3.17 V  
fan1:        2136 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan2:         724 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan3:        1318 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan4:        1094 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
temp1:        +34.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp2:        +42.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = thermal diode
temp3:        +39.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = thermal diode
cpu0_vid:    +0.000 V
intrusion0:  ALARM
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't get it to work for 2 weeks, i removed XSensors and switched to Psensor. I'd even say it's a better choice for this task.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo sensors-detect
```

Comment: I had done this before to get the `sensors` command working. Did it again. It changed nothing. XSensors still displayes only one temp